# Problem with critical section using Retrant Lock with Condition

Tags: java, locking, java-threads

I have a small project to synchronize multiple (two classes: ships, cars with a few instances with shared bufor class called Harbour) threads at the same time. They will be performing certain action on it. But I can't start with that until I synchronized the threads named "cars" in the Harbour. The Harbour has limited capacity and if this capacity is reached the "car" threads should be waiting until they will get signal that there's a free space to enter. I've used Retrant Lock with Condition but it doesn't work as I think.

```
public class Harbour {
    final Lock protectNr;
    final Condition protectNrCon;
    int capacity;
    int nrOfCars;

    public Harbour(int capacity) {
        this.capacity = capacity;
        this.protectNr = new ReentrantLock();
        this.protectNrCon = protectNr.newCondition();
    }

    public void carEnterHarbour(String name) {
        try {
            protectNr.lock();
            if (this.nrOfCars == this.capacity)
                protectNrCon.await();

            nrOfCars++;
            System.out.println(name + " enters");
            System.out.println("Number of cars:" + this.nrOfCars);
            protectNr.unlock();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Error");
        }
    }

    public void carLeavingHarbour(String name) {
        try {
            protectNr.lock();
            this.nrOfCars--;
            protectNrCon.signal();
            System.out.println(name + " leaving");
            System.out.println("Number of cars:" + this.nrOfCars);
        } finally {
            protectNr.unlock();
        }
    }
}

public class Car extends Thread {
    Harbour harbour;
    public Car(Harbour harbour, String name) {
        super(name);
        this.harbour = harbour;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            harbour.carEnterHarbour(getName());
            harbour.carLeavingHarbour(getName());
        }
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        int harbourCapacity = 20;
        final Harbour harbour = new Harbour(harbourCapacity);
        int nrOfCars = 500;
        Car[] cars = new Car[nrOfCars];
        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCars; i++)
            cars[i] = new Car(harbour, "Car-" + i);

        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCars; i++)
            cars[i].start();

        for (int i = 0; i < nrOfCars; i++)
            cars[i].join();
    }
}
```

What I was expecting after executing this code:

```
Car-386 leaving
Number of cars:**19**
Car-300 enters
Number of cars:**20**
Car-300 leaving
Number of cars:**19**
```

What I got:

```
Car-386 leaving
Number of cars:**20**
Car-300 enters
Number of cars:**21**
Car-295 enters
Number of cars:**22**
```

I also try to **change int capacity** to **volatile int capacity** and add some busy waiting but didn't work at all.
It looks like Threads are not block on Condition and I wonder why is this happening?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) initialized with the harbor capacity? A car wanting to enter the harbor would the `aquire()` a slot and on leaving `release()` a slot.

Comment: For this piece of code i think i could use it, but there will be more cases when i need to decrement and increment nrOfCars and this operation need to be done by only single one thread at time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation for [`Condition`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html) warns that spurious wakeups might occur (emphasis mine):

> When waiting upon a Condition, a "*spurious wakeup*" is permitted to occur, in general, as a concession to the underlying platform semantics. This has little practical impact on most application programs as a Condition **should always be waited upon in a loop**, testing the state predicate that is being waited for. An implementation is free to remove the possibility of spurious wakeups but it is recommended that applications programmers always assume that they can occur and so always wait in a loop.

Your code doesn't honor that warning.

Your `carEnterHarbour()` must take this possibility of spurious wakeups into account and needs

```
        while(this.nrOfCars == this.capacity){
            protectNrCon.await();
        }
```

instead of the simple `if` statement.

---

Depending on your requirements it might be easier to use a [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html):

```
public class Harbour {
    final Semaphore slots;

    public Harbour(int capacity){
        this.slots = new Semaphore(capacity);
    }

    public void carEnterHarbour(String name) {
        try{
            slots.acquire();
        }catch (InterruptedException e){
            System.out.println("Error");
        }

    }
    public void carLeavingHarbour(String name) {
        slots.release();
    }
}
```

Note that when using a `Semaphore` you don't have those locks in place when entering / leaving the Harbour and therefore it is difficult to get that ordered "car entering" / "car leaving" output together with the number of currently available slots.

Comment: Didn't know that's a thing with Threads. In classes at the university we haven't been told that this kind of situation can occur sometimes.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In the carEnterHarbour method, you are calling await() on the protectNrCon condition, which causes the current thread to wait until it is signaled. However, you are not calling signal() anywhere in the carEnterHarbour method. This means that once a thread enters the if block, it will always wait indefinitely on the condition.

You should consider calling signal() on the protectNrCon condition after you increment nrOfCars and print the message, so that other threads waiting on the condition can be unblocked.

Additionally, you should call await() in a loop to ensure that the thread waits until the condition is true, rather than waiting indefinitely. Here is an example of how you can modify the carEnterHarbour method:

```html
public void carEnterHarbour(String name) {
    try {
        protectNr.lock();
        while (this.nrOfCars == this.capacity) {
            protectNrCon.await();
        }
        nrOfCars++;
        System.out.println(name+" enters");
        System.out.println("Number of cars:" + this.nrOfCars);
        protectNrCon.signal();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    } finally {
        protectNr.unlock();
    }
}
```

Comment: But the thread is calling signal() when using CarLeavingHarbour() method, so the other thread currently awaiting should be informed that he can enter or it's not?